# Where can I find System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.dll?

Tags: .net, mvvm, inversion-of-control, .net-assembly, caliburn.micro

I just started using Caliburn.Micro, and it says to import the

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization
```

in

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.dll
```

but i can't find the assembly in the .NET assembly reference explorer!

Can you help me please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install Caliburn.Micro via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/). This will pull in the required dependencies. There is also a [Caliburn.Micro.Start](http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Start/) NuGet package which will give you MEF based IoC configuration.